# How can I disable ubuntuone-client from running everytime I login?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need to manually do 'ps and kill -9' to kill it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively if you prefer not having everything listed under Startup Application, disable `Ubuntu One` at login:

```
echo "Hidden=true" | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop
```

Show Ubuntu One in Startup Applications:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop
```

You can use the second command I posted to replace MorganSBailey's command and not effect all startup entries

Comment: One should not edit these files in their lcoation in /etc. If you wish to manage how they are used, then the autostart .desktop files you wish to change should first be copied into `~/.config/autostart/` and edited there.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`
```

That will unhide the applications hidden by default in Startup Applications. Now go to Startup Applications, find the Ubuntu One entry and untick it. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the `Ubuntu One` control panel application from the launcher or dash, and go to the `Settings` tab, you can disable the `Connect automatically when computer starts` option. This will keep it from connecting automatically on start.

If you do need to actually not run it for some reason, you should do the following:

```
#: mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
#: cp /etc/xdg/autostart/ubuntuone-lauch.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
#: echo "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false" >> ~/.config/autostart/ubuntuone-launch.desktop
```

This will disable the launcher program from running on start. However, it will not disable other applications requesting that `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` be launched, via DBus, so that they can communicate with it. If any applications do request connection to it, then DBus will automatically launch it.